# Redirects, seo and site internal search engine

Tags: seo, redirects, search

For a CMS constraint I have to survive with, the search on my site works this way:

1. the user fills search values and submit
2. a page of results is then shown with a list of links
3. the user clicks on some link and *gets redirected* to the detail page

The thing to note is that when the user clicks at #3, it won't get immediately access the result detail page `/realestate/1`, but there is an intermediate access to `/redirect/realestates/1` and then the redirect to the final page `/realestate/1`.

I'd like to know:

- can this approach impact negatively from a SEO point of view?
- which redirect would be more appropriate? Currently it's HTTP code 302 found.

PS:
I see there are other questions about SEO and redirects, but there the context is landing page and my scenario is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use robots.txt to block search engines from following any links in your site search.

Comment: Reasoning on your idea I think I'll use [rel="nofollow"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?&answer=96569); it has the same effect but it's more granular. This way the search engine is still able to index other contents I care of in the search page. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's fine to have them index the main search page, but it's standard practice to block access to any actual search results. And do you consider your search page to be a good landing target for incoming search engine traffic?

Comment: Yes, it'll work as a landing page. In fact when no search filters are applied, a paginated list of result links (with nofollow to prevent the redirect) is presented to the user or search engine.